# Filter array based on it's keys by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to filter an array with data objects with it's keys based on another array.

I need to show/hide columns of a table, which is based on data like this:

```
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "A",
    description: "number 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "B",
    description: "number 2"
  }
]
```

This results in a table with three columns ("ID", "Name" and "Description") and two rows.

I now have a dropdown which contains one checkbox for each table header.

These inputs get stored in another array, so when you click "id" in the dropdown, the array looks like this:

`var selectedColumns = ["id"]`

..or when you select "id" and "name":

`var selectedColumns = ["id", "name"]`

I now want to filter my `data` array based on the `selectedColumns` array.

I already tried the `filter` function, but I can't wrap my head around on how to do it right:

```
   if (selectedColumns) {
    if (selectedColumns.length != 0) {
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        var keys = Object.keys(item)
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
          if (!selectedColumns.includes(key)) {
            delete item[key];
          }
        })

        return true
      })
    }
```

Background: This table should be a reusable Vue component, so all the keys ("id", "name", ..) and the table headers change accordingly, which prevents hardcoding the logic.

Comment: Do you mean you want the elements of `data` to have only the keys defined in `selectedColumns`?

Comment: `...I now want to filter my data array based on the selectedColumns array...` Does this means you want to hide the columns which are not in the `selectedColumns` arrays?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Exactly.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes.

Comment: That's not a `filter`, that's a `map`, like Nina's answer specifies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the wanted keys and map a new array with new objects with only the wanted properties.

```js
function getProperties(array, keys) {
    return array.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));
}

var data = [{ id: "1", name: "A", description: "number 1" }, { id: "2", name: "B", description: "number 2" }];

console.log(getProperties(data, ['id', 'name']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An even shorter approach with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
function getProperties(array, keys) {
    return array.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));
}

var data = [{ id: "1", name: "A", description: "number 1" }, { id: "2", name: "B", description: "number 2" }];

console.log(getProperties(data, ['id', 'name']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it works:

```js
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "A",
    description: "number 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "B",
    description: "number 2"
  }
];

var selectedColumns = ["id", "name"];


if (selectedColumns) {
    if (selectedColumns.length != 0) {
      var data = data.filter(function(item) {
        var keys = Object.keys(item)
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
          if (!selectedColumns.includes(key)) {
            delete item[key];
          }
        })

        return true
      })
    }
    console.log(data);
}
```